# How to remove the upper grey bar in this app?

Tags: android

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to remove that grey bar in app containing the app name..

Comment: Look carefully at the main layout XML.

Comment: Show your theme settings, build.gradle file,  AndroidManifest file & xml layout of your Activity.

Comment: Check my answer hope this may help you . If my answer helps you then please mark as a right my answer from tick mark otherwise i'm gonna remove this answer brother :https://www.google.com/search?q=right+mark+as+an+answer+stackoverflow&sxsrf=ACYBGNQVsfXj9VeT9WRKWerxeSRoAMe2uQ:1579936139192&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQk-DimJ7nAhWBc30KHdm9CGAQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1517&bih=730#imgrc=9_JN49MpzDykBM

Answer (score 2):

Add in Manifest.xml file

```
 <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**style.xml**

> `<resources> Add below here  </resources>`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    }
}
```

Follow above steps

hope this may help you

Comment: Check my answer hope this may help you . If my answer helps you then please mark as a right my answer from tick mark otherwise i'm gonna remove this answer brother :https://www.google.com/search?q=right+mark+as+an+answer+stackoverflow&sxsrf=ACYBGNQVsfXj9VeT9WRKWerxeSRoAMe2uQ:1579936139192&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQk-DimJ7nAhWBc30KHdm9CGAQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1517&bih=730#imgrc=9_JN49MpzDykBM

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line in your menifest -

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

for full screen use below -

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

If you want to do it programatically use below code -

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

for full screen -

```
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Use according to your feasibility.